# Haskell: RandomGen drops half of values

Tags: haskell, random

I am writing a simple deterministic Random Number generator, based on the [xorshift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xorshift). The goal here is not to get a cryptographically secure or statistically perfect (pseudo-)random number generator, but to be able to archieve the same deterministic sequence of semi-random numbers across programming languages.

My Haskell program looks like follows:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving #-}
module SimpleRNG where

import Data.Word (Word32)
import Data.Bits (xor, shift)
import System.Random (RandomGen(..))
import Control.Arrow

(|>) :: a -> (a -> b) -> b
(|>) x f = f x
infixl 0 |>

newtype SeedState = SeedState Word32
  deriving (Eq, Show, Enum, Bounded)

seed :: Integral a => a -> SeedState
seed = SeedState . fromIntegral

rand_r :: SeedState -> (Word32, SeedState)
rand_r (SeedState num) = (res, SeedState res)
  where
    res = num
      |> xorshift 13
      |> xorshift (-17)
      |> xorshift 5
    xorshift :: Int -> Word32 -> Word32
    xorshift amount x = x `xor` (shift x amount)

instance RandomGen SeedState where
  next seed_state = (first fromIntegral) $ rand_r seed_state
    where
  genRange seed_state = (fromEnum (minBound `asTypeOf` seed_state),
                fromEnum (maxBound `asTypeOf` seed_state))

  split seed_state@(SeedState num) =  (seed_state', inverted_seed_state')
    where
      (_, seed_state') = next seed_state
      (_, inverted_seed_state') = next inverted_seed_state
      inverted_seed_state = SeedState (maxBound - num)
```

Now, for some reason, when running

```
take 10 $ System.Random.randoms (seed 42) :: [Word32]
```

it returns only the 'odd' results, compared to the output of the following Python program:

```
class SeedState(object):
    def __init__(self, seed = 42):
        self.data = seed

def rand_r(rng_state):
    num = rng_state.data
    num ^= (num << 13) % (2 ** 32)
    num ^= (num >> 17) % (2 ** 32)
    num ^= (num << 5) % (2 ** 32)
    rng_state.data = num
    return num


__global_rng_state = SeedState(42)

def rand():
    global __global_rng_state
    return rand_r(__global_rng_state)

def seed(seed):
    global __global_rng_state
    __global_rng_state = SeedState(seed)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for x in range(0, 10):
        print(rand())
```

It seems like the internals of the System.Random module do some weird trickery with the return result of the generator 
(calling

```
map fst $ take 10 $ iterate (\(_, rng) -> rand_r rng) (rand_r $ seed 42)
```

gives the result I'd expect).

This is odd, since the type returned by the generator is already a `Word32`, so it could/should just be passed on unaltered without any remapping happening.

What is going on here, and is there a way to plug this xorshift-generator into  System.Random in a way that returns the same results?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is to do with the behaviour of [System.Random.randoms](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/random-1.1/docs/src/System-Random.html#randoms), which repeatedly applies `random` to a `RandomGen`, not `next`.

```
class Random a where
    ...
    random :: (RandomGen g) => g -> (a, g)
```

The `Random` class is what allows you to reuse `RandomGen` instances across different enums, and the instance for `Word32` (as well as nearly all other types) is defined as

```
instance Random Word32     where randomR = randomIvalIntegral; random = randomBounded
```

`randomBounded` just calls `randomR`, so the behaviour of `random` is decided by `

```
 randomIvalIntegral (l,h) = randomIvalInteger (toInteger l, toInteger h)
```

`randomIvalInteger` is an interesting function, you can read the source [here](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/random-1.1/docs/src/System-Random.html#randomIvalInteger). It's actually causing your problem because the function will discard a certain number of intermediate values based on the range of the generator and the range being generated over.

To get the values you want, you just need to use `next` instead - the easiest way would just be to define

```
randoms' g = x : (randoms' g') where (x, g') = next g
```

Comment: So if I understand it correctly, `randomIvalInteger` deems the range of a `Word32` smaller than a `Word32`, and therefore skips every second value of my generator? :'(.

Comment: That's not the reason for skipping. `randomIvalInteger` has a helper function which skips values based on a `mag` (magnitude) argument. The argument starts at `1`, is multiplied by `(highest enum value) - (lowest enum value) + 1` every iteration, and values are skipped until it's bigger than `((highest range value) - (lowest range value) + 1) * 1000`. In your case, the range is equal to the whole of `Word32`, so that target is exceeded every other iteration (since `(size of Word32)^2 > (size of Word32) * 1000`. There's no way to have a generator which doesn't skip using `randomIvalInteger`.